# Constantly evolving dynamic UI

Tags: dynamic-ui, changes

> AI will recognize usage patterns and create subtle changes to the UI.
>   These small changes will have a compound effect over time, designing
>   the ideal interface to accommodate a persons needs and abilities.

[Reference for the above quote](https://uxdesign.cc/toward-a-more-human-user-interface-with-artificial-intelligence-7bbee17ff30d#.90e0k635b)

What is the name (if there is one) of this concept, where the UI changes to adapt to the usage. Just to be clear, i'm not talking about the change of serving of more personalized content, but more about changing the UI itself.

Example:

User always opens the navigation drawer when the arrive on the app. App learns over time, and automatically keeps the drawer open.

I'm a novice designer and more of a developer and I've been researching on Machine Learning for a while now and hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard a term which describes changing the UI based on AI, but I know of some similar concepts that might be a good starting point for you:

**Progressive Enhancement**

This is enhancing a website based on the person's device. If they have a faster phone, or a faster internet connection, or a larger screen, then more things can be shown to them (High quality images, animation effects, etc.)

**Progressive Reduction**

This is more similar to what you're describing. Progressive reduction is taking elements of the user interface OUT because the user has become more familiar with the application. For example, the Facebook app might remove the labels from the bottom navigation bar once the person has been using it for two weeks, because at that point it's visual clutter and the person knows what each icon means.

**Remembering UI choices**

I'm not sure what to call this, but a lot of software remembers your UI choices for next time you use it. For example, Adobe Photoshop remembers the positions of your panels and which ones should be open.

This is simple, and has happened for many years already, but AI could be used to improve it. Perhaps the computer or webapp knows who is using the software without them having to log in, and changes the UI to their settings automatically?

I also recently heard about cars which change your settings (Generally in the onboard software) because each person gets their own key, and the car knows who is starting it based on their unique key.

Comment: Thanks for answering Anthony. The concepts which you have mentioned, did you coin the terms or are they well known? 

I think the idea i'm talking about is a mix of everything you've mentioned. Except it happens within that specific device itself. Maybe this can be pulled off with lesser complexity without AI, i'm just not aware of it. I like your car example, that seems like the seeds for the idea i'm talking about :)

Comment: Progressive Enhancement and Progressive Reduction are not my terms. A quick Google will give you articles written about each. I tried to find a technical term for "Remembering UI choices", but I couldn't!